# Using one power supply for my SunFire x4100

Tags: power-supply-unit, sun

Is there a risk on using just one power supply on this server?, I just found out that you can POST and run stuff with only one power supply (even tho I still get the LED errors) , I read the manual but it doesn't say much about running it like that

Comment: `Is there a risk on using just one power supply on this server?` - The obvious risk is that if the power supply fails then your server would lose power, ungracefully shutting off, which could cause data loss, an unrecoverable/unbootable OS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Second power supply is for redundancy. It's safe to have only one (until it works).